# SOAP request in Node using SSL

Tags: node.js, web-services, ssl, curl, soap

Recently, I've been working with SOAP requests.

I've managed to use the node-soap module to be able to send successful requests to http services. However, now I want to use it to send a request to an external ***https*** web service.

I have managed to send SSL requests using a .cer file with cUrl. But when trying this in the node.js code, I am getting errors. From what I have read (see [ClientSSLSecurity](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap#clientsslsecurity) on the node-soap module), I need a key (in .key format) and a certificate (in .pem format). I  do not know whether this requires a private key or not? I have managed to extract a public key from my .cer file.

I have tried the below code:

```
var createSoapClient = function (){
    soap.createClient(url, function(err,client){
        client.setSecurity(new soap.ClientSSLSecurity(
            'mycert.cer',
            'pubkey.key'
        ));
        if(err)
            console.error(err);
        else {
            client.MyOperation(args,function(err,response){
                if(err){
                    console.error(err);
                }
                else{
                    console.log(response);
                }
            })
        }
    });
}
```

however, this results in the below error message:

```
Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
```

What am I missing? Is it a private key?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

According to package found on npm, regarding ClientSSLSecurity :

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/axl-node-soap
https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap-x509
https://www.npmjs.com/package/strong-soap#clientsslsecurity
https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap#clientsslsecurity
```

I assume that you've pass wrong argument to ClientSSLSecurity. It seems to take **the key then the certificate**, you're passing **the certificate then the key**.

Try to do something like this :

```
   client.setSecurity(new soap.ClientSSLSecurity(
        'pubkey.key',
        'mycert.cer'

    ));
```

Which package are you using ?

---

You're couple key/cert is probably wrong

Try to regenerate the certificate :

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -nodes -keyout key.pem -out csr.pem
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in csr.pem -signkey key.pem -out server.crt
```

then pass key.pem as the key and server.crt as the certificate.

Comment: Same error unfortunately, I'm using the node-soap module [link](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap).